# SwiftUI, macOS Menu Component Custom

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu

Do you know how to remove the indicator from the Menu Component?
My minimum OS version is 11.0

```
    Menu {
    Button(action: {
        changeLanguage("ko")
    }) {
        Text("한국어")
    }
    Button(action: {
        changeLanguage("en")
    }) {
        Text("English")
    }
    Button(action: {
        changeLanguage("ja")
    }) {
        Text("日本語")
    }
    Button(action: {
        changeLanguage("zh-Hans")
    }) {
        Text("中国话")
    }
} label : {
    Image("globe")

}
.frame(width: 40, height: 25)
.menuStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuStyle())
```

[image]

I'd like to get rid of the arrow on the right side.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `showsMenuIndicator` is deprecated. Please try something like this:

```swift
    Menu {
    
    }
    .menuIndicator(.hidden)
```

Comment: The `.hidden` indicator option has an issue with its visual spacing on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```swift
.menuStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuStyle(showsMenuIndicator: false))
```